# Next js 13. Client component is very slow and don't update states

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am kinda new to next js, so don't angry on me too much.

I have a client component that supposed to load new posts from my API after click on "Load more" button:

```
'use client';
import PostCard from "@/components/PostCard";
import {useState} from "react";


const MultiplePosts = ({posts, session, slug}) => {
    const [Posts, setPosts] = useState(posts);
    const [CurrentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const HandleLoadMore = async () => {
        let NewPage = CurrentPage + 1
        let newData = await GetMorePostsUserPage(session, slug, NewPage)
        const allPosts = [...Posts, ...newData];
        setPosts(allPosts);
        setCurrentPage(prevState => prevState + 1)
    }

    return (
        <div className={"post-infinite-container"}>
            {
                Posts.map((post) => (
                    <PostCard
                        key={post.id}
                        post={post}
                        comments={post.comments}
                        session={session}
                    />
                ))
            }
            <button data-next-page={CurrentPage} type={"button"} onClick={() => HandleLoadMore()}>Load More</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I use useState and trying to update posts array with setPosts. MultiplePosts component sits inside server component - page.jsx. PostCard component is client as well as MultiplePosts. My main problem with all this thing is that after click the button - no newly fetched posts are appeared on the page and CurrentPage variable is not updated as well. So, when I click "Load more" button one more time, I sent a request with the same "page" GET param. Moreover, this client component is extremely slow in common sense. I forced to wait about 10 seconds to open developer tools, and after click "Load more" button, I can't do anything. And close tab is browser too!

I just don't know what to do now. Please, tell me, if I am doing something wrong!

UPD:
Page.jsx(server component) that contains MultiplePosts component:

```
export default async function Page(props){
    const {slug} = props.params;
    const {user, posts, subscriptions} = await getUserPageBySlug(slug);
    const session = await getServerSession(options);
    return (
        <>
            <UserCover user={user} />
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row align-items-start">
                    <div className="user-card-container col-12 col-lg-3 order-lg-1 order-1 sticky-lg-top sticky-user">
                        <UserCard user={user} session={session} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-lg-6 order-lg-2 order-3">
                        <Filters />
                        <MultiplePosts posts={posts} session={session} slug={slug}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-lg-3 order-lg-3 order-2">
                        <SubscriptionCard user={user} subscriptions={subscriptions} session={session}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

PostCard.jsx (Client one) that is inside MultiplePosts

```
export default function PostCard({post, comments, session}) {
    const isAuthor = post.author.slug === session.user.name
    return (
        <div id={"post-item-" + post.id} className="card p-0 mb-3">
            <div className="post-header px-3 pt-3">
                <PostHeader post={post} isAuthor={isAuthor}/>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="post-content px-3">
                <PostContent post={post} isAuthor={isAuthor}/>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="post-footer px-3 pb-3">
                <PostFooter post={post} comments={comments} session={session}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, are you sure the slowness is due to this component ?

Comment: The biggest problem of this, is that I can't see anything wrong too! And I disappointed more not cause of performance, but cause of button press don't update the states.. 
I'll update my question and add two components that bound with this one. Maybe you could see something goes wrong there.

Comment: try to remove this component and check if the slowness is still there. Moreover you can add a console.log into your component to see if there is any infinite rerender behavior

Comment: Removed it. Slowness still here